# Nice html output of a HashTable

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have a filled 
                  HashTable<MyObject>,

MyObject contains a number and a String.

What I need is the easy way to format the output so that it can be output to a html table and browsed via web-browser.

I look for both framework - specific solutions and simple libraries that return a string with wrapped with html tags fields.

this can look like this:

```
     lib.setColNum(3);
     lib.getColumns(0).bindField...
```

etc

Are there ready and easy to use solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You might use the displaytag library:

http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/

It gives you a lot of ways to dispaly data and you can also export your table to excel, pdf, xml en some other formats as well, if you want to ...

Hope this helps,
Jan